# Percent Of Total in Quicksight

Tags: percentage, amazon-quicksight

percentOfTotal(

sum(resubscriberNumber), [count(customerid)]

)

I want this to compute on a column level and not on the row level.

It is computing on the row level. Lets' say I want %of subscribers of total users. How can I achieve this?

If I do it in the simplest way to create a calculated field (subscribers/total users) * 100. Quicksight is giving an error.